# Tricky ruby on rails problem. Does an easy solution exist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, radio-button

I hope my question is understandable, else I'm glad to clarify.

We have this sport event coming up, and I have the pleasure to register the people. :)

Facts:

- one can have a team of 5-10 persons.
- Need to know the order in which the people start.
- Need to know who the team leader is.

I did a form in the following style:

1. `o [____Write first name here___]` *<--- this is a textfield*
2. `o [____Write second name here__]`
3. `o [___________ ... ____________]`
4. ...

the "o" is a radio-button, used to pick the team leader.

I have a model **Person** and a model **Team**. Every team has a **leader_id** (which is one of the Person IDs). Furthermore every team `:has_many` persons.

In the controller I have

```
def create
   @team = Team.new(params[:team])
   @team.save #just assume there are no errors
end
```

In the view I have (for the radio-buttons):

```
<input id="team_leader_id_**????**"
       name="team[leader_id]"
       type="radio"
       value="**????**"
/>

<input id="team_leader_id_**????**"
       name="team[leader_id]"
       type="radio"
       value="**????**"
/>    
# etc.
```

**My question: What should I put at `**????**` ?**

I don't know the IDs of the persons yet, as they haven't been created. I have to put some meta-ID there, which ruby on rails recognizes and links everything correctly?

**You don't have to read the rest (it describes the hack I'm using)**

As said, at the moment I'm doing an ugly hack: first save the Team (without generating a leader), then fetch the same team from the db, get its people, and find the first person matching the value of

```
params[:team][:leader_id].
```

Finally saving this person's ID in the field of leader_id of the team.

But this code is inefficient, huge and buggy, that I suspect there is an easier way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The radios should have the same name i.e.

```
<input id="team_persons_attributes_0_leader_id"
       name="team[persons_attributes][leader_id]"
       type="radio"
       value="0"
/>
<input id="team_persons_attributes_1_leader_id"
       name="team[persons_attributes][leader_id]"
       type="radio"
       value="1"
/>
<input id="team_persons_attributes_2_leader_id"
       name="team[persons_attributes][leader_id]"
       type="radio"
       value="2"
/>
```

This way there can only be one selected (via the browsers internal radio button mechanism) and `params[:team][:persons_attributes][:leader_id]` will contain an index to `params[:team][:persons]` which will be the leader's name.

to obtain the id

```
team = Team.create(params[:team])
params[:team][:persons].each_with_index{|name, idx|
   person = Persons.create(:name => name)
   #assuming no errors
   team.leader_id = person.id if params[:team][:persons_attributes][:leader_id] == idx
}
```

Comment: thanks. I updated my post. Silly mistake, problem remains. :)

Comment: just to clarify: ruby on rails sets team.leader_id to whatever I specified in the "value" attribute. With your example this could for example be "1" if I choose the second one. But I really want to have the ID of the person in that field, and not 1.

Comment: the id can be obtained using my example by params[:team][:persons][params[:team][:persons_attributes][:leader_id]][:id]  - i'll update my answer to explain in more detail.

Comment: nice, tanks :) Not a one line solution, but probably there is none.

Answer (score 1):

It seems as though you are submitting a number of users in one go with one of them flagged as the team leader.  In this case you could construct something like:

```
<%= radio_button_tag "[team][leader]","[1]" %>
<%= radio_button_tag "[team][leader]","[2]" %>>
```

Then in the controller create the people (using nested attributes?), then simply look up the ID of the one flagged as the leader for the team record.